# Cannot run python file, asks to relink libraries

Tags: ubuntu, python, libraries, python3

I'm trying to run a python file, but it doesn't allow me to, showing an error:

```
python3: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1` with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1` for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime`
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Seems to me that this issue is related to some python package, since other python modules run perfectly. How do I fix that?

Comment: Copying modules files manually from other systems usually does not end well. I have a hunch you are not telling us the whole story.

Comment: Had a similar problem trying to use cx_Oracle. The root cause was completely unrelated - had to install libaio. Interestingly enough, the misleading relink message shows in Python 3, while in Python 2 it correctly informs the lack of libaio, trying to run the program in Python 2 was the way to discover the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently the issue was related to the opencv-python library. I tried to open a python session and import that module mannually but it produced the same error. I removed that module from pip and installed it again with `apt install python3-opencv`. It worked.

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: Installing `cuDNN` solves the issue with tensorflow-gpu. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19375

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin thanks! that saved me a lot of time.  maybe consider adding it as an answer to be more visible

Comment: @thang The question was closed and, hence, it accepts no other answers.